# Are there any feats improving Lay On Hands besides Hands of the Healer and Great Charisma?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, class-feature, paladin

Some time ago my player had asked me if there is a way to improve his 10 Paladin/10 Grayguard's lay on hands ability, so healing and Devastating Touch would improve.

I have searched through most of the books, but the only feats I could find were **Hands of the Healer** and **Great Charisma**. I was unable to find anything more. Are there any Dragon Magazine or 3rd-party feats that could do so?

Comment: I appreciate this question's focus. Will another question ask about, for example, magic items?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very few feats published in official supplements or *Dragon* touch lay on hands:

- Action Healing (*Faiths of Eberron*): spend an action point to lay on hands with 50% extra healing, lay on hands as a swift action, or lay on hands from up to 30 feet away. Even if we assume you’re using action points, action points are way more valuable than those effects.
- Azure Touch (*Magic of Incarnum*): Grants 1 point of essentia, and allows you to basically trade away essentia for the day to gain another use of lay on hands (or wholeness of body). Essentia is way more limited and valuable than uses of lay on hands, so that’s a pretty terrible trade—the bonus point of essentia is by far the more valuable thing from this feat.
- Serenity (*Dragon Compendium*): Use Wisdom instead of Charisma for all paladin abilities, lay on hands included. **Fantastic** feat, but because of divine grace, not because of lay on hands.
- Touch of Silver (*Faiths of Eberron*): Burn a use of turn undead to make lay on hands hurt lycanthropes and evil outsiders as if they were undead. Which is, again, a terrible trade.

In three out of four cases, these feats involve trading away some limited resource in order to get some minor effect: these are terrible feats. Serenity is good, but not particularly because of lay on hands.

Which kind of works out, because lay on hands is a very weak ability. It is a really bad idea to invest feats, which are very scarce and extremely valuable, into it.

I do not know of any third-party feats that significantly change this conclusion, but I am also generally unfamiliar with third-party material.

Comment: Having been beaten to this answer therefore having recently reread Action Healing, *if* a consistent source of free action points—like from the 5th-level Sor/Wiz spell *unfettered heroism* [trans] (*Races of Eberron* 190-1)—is available (not inconceivable but difficult) , the feat Action Healing doesn't seem an utterly-out-of-the-question choice (like the feats Dirty Fighting, Master Swimmer, or Unpredictable Blow). I mean, being able to use lay on hands—which can deal damage—as a swift action *is* kind of okay. (Standard advice to play a crusader instead notwithstanding.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan I’m now imagining DMM-Persist-*unfettered heroism*-Action Healing-*lay on hands*, which is kind of ridiculous. Also, untenable for a paladin at any rate.

Comment: Persisting *unfettered heroism*, like, *at all* is pretty bonkers, really. Anyway, I'll upvote this answer (it covers the official feats my answer would've covered) if it mentions that it ignores third-party feats and that including *Dragon* magazine feats adds no feats to the list (because *Dragon* doesn't have any feats that help).

Comment: @HeyICanChan Ignoring third-party material is default as far I’m concerned, and since the question mentions *Dragon* I would take it as assumed it was considered (and the fact that the list includes nothing from there indicates *Dragon* has nothing). I’ll clarify if it makes you feel better, though.

Comment: Normally I'd totally agree about not needing to mention either, but the question *specifically* asks about third party and *Dragon* material, so *not* mentioning them seems a mistake.  The wordplay makes this a better answer anyway. `;-)`

Comment: @HeyICanChan Oh! I did miss that bit about 3rd-party. That... would be much more difficult to try to assess. I don’t think I’m qualified to do so; I know little of 3.5e third-party material.

Comment: Azure Touch could be used with another incarnum feat (Psycarnum Infusion and being a psionic character capable of gaining focus - use a feat or level for this) which allows you to expend your focus in exchange for treating a given incarnum receptacle as if it was full for one round. Reuse as often as you can afford actions to make your Concentration check to refocus.

Answer (score 1):

### Azure Touch + Psycarnum Infusion can do it...

Azure Touch could be used with another incarnum feat (Psycarnum Infusion and being a psionic character capable of gaining focus - use a feat or level for this) which allows you to expend your focus in exchange for treating a given incarnum receptacle as if it was full for one round. Reuse as often as you can afford actions to make your Concentration check to refocus.

**However, your DM may view this as over-usable and not go for it.**

Check first.

Comment: According to Table 8–2: Actions in Combat (*PH* 141), usually using an extraordinary ability takes a standard action, but what kind of action is to realize the benefit of the feat Psycarnum Infusion? (That is, if takes a standard action to use, the paladin's gonna need the feat Action Healing, too!)

Comment: to use the feat you have to expend your focus. generally, it is considered either a free action or part of another action, more or less the same as using the concentration skill itself. for example: http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/skills/concentration.htm when expending focus on a concentration check it doesn't require an action at all. On the other hand, that is a skill check. Some may not consider that to apply when expending it on a feat, power, or class ability - though again, usually considered part of those actions and not an action itself.

Comment: I don't recall if feats are considered EX or NA off the top of my head, either. What do non-declared feats default to, if anything?